# They used to be / were good friends

Tags: grammar

This exercise below is from my English book. I noticed that the author took the example from Macmillan Dictionary [here](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/license/thats-english/dictionary/american/friend_1) (1.b)

> They_____good friends, but they’ve fallen out recently.
>
> ```
> a. used to be
> b. would be
> c. were
> d. are
> ```

The given answer is (a), but I'm not sure if (c) can be a valid answer in this case. Is there any difference in meaning if I replace 'used to be' with 'were' in this sentence? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**they used to be** means "they were, but are no longer".

**they were** means only "they were".

Thus, **were** is valid there. However, if the sentence did not include "but they've fallen out recently", and you wanted to convey the idea they there had been a falling out, you would need to use **used to be**.

Comment: It's a bit more awkward (though probably not impossible) to contrive a context where ***would be*** would be acceptable in OP's context. But I don't have any problem at all with ***are***. People can be good friends for decades even if they often fall out for short periods before getting the relationship back on an even keel.

Comment: But there we're straying beyond grammar into the nature of friendship.  We should simplify the example:  *He used to live in London.*

Comment: _Any_ of the choices could be "correct," although as @FumbleFingers says, "would be" requires a complicated context. I'm willing to guess that this excerpt is from yet another "English book" written by an author whose first language is not English...

Comment: @P. E. Dant: In this particular case I wouldn't like to say the choice of alternatives makes it significantly more likely the "test-setter" wasn't a native speaker. After all, reasonably competent non-native speakers should be capable of realising that although *one* answer is pragmatically far more likely to occur in real-world contexts, some or all of the others would be fine in certain *other* contexts. It just reminds me of dumbo "tests" like *What is the next number in the series **3, 1, 4, 1, 5...**?* (Is it ***9*** from pi? ***1*** to complete the 3rd "digit couplet"? Something else?)